# Dart Switch expression curly braces when using Map

Tags: dart

I am new to dart and Flutter, in the following switch expression I do not understand the first part wrapped in curly brackets. I have gone through dart tutorial but none of the sections mentioned this type of example.

```
factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return switch (json) {
      {
        'userId': int userId,
        'id': int id,
        'title': String title,
      } =>
        Album(
          userId: userId,
          id: id,
          title: title,
        ),
      _ => throw const FormatException('Failed to load album.'),
    };
  }
```

What exactly is the below part doing

```
      {
        'userId': int userId,
        'id': int id,
        'title': String title,
      }
```

I do not understand the part of code just above

Comment: See https://dart.dev/language/patterns and https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/dart-patterns-records.. it's a pattern matching the contents of the incoming Map and destructuring the value.

Answer (score 1):

Dart evolves, actually every day has updates.

Firstly, it's a named constructor to construct objects using a map, `Map<String,dynamic>` called json.

in the body of the constructor: he switches over the json using `switch expression`.

**The First Case** : switch expression doesn't have case keyword and cases are separated using commas.

so, what does the following block make

```
      {
        'userId': int userId,
        'id': int id,
        'title': String title,
      }
```

english translation of that code: if the json eg: Map has the following structure (

if the first item's key is 'userId' and the type of it's value is integer,

if the second item's key is 'id' and the type of it's value is integer,

if the third item's key is 'title' and the type of it's value is String,
) if so, return an Album object.

In short, **it just checks the structure of the passed Map**.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The function's return statement returns the result of a `switch` *expression*.
A switch expression has the form `switch (matchedValueExpression) { pattern => expression, ... , pattern => expression }` (optional trailing comma allowed).

The block you ask about is before a `=>`, so it's a pattern. In particular, it's a map pattern.

```
{ 'userId': int userId, 'id': int id, 'title': String title,}
```

This pattern matches a value that implements `Map`, and where the `String` keys `'userId'`, `'id'` and `'title'` have associated values that are `int`, `int` and `String` values respectively.

If that's satisfied, the pattern matches, the values are bound to the new variables `userId`, `id` and `title`, and the switch evaluates to the value of the expression after the `=>`, here creating an `Album` object using the variables bound by the pattern match. That's the value of the `switch` expression, which is then returned by the `return` statement.

The other switch case is `_ => throw const FormatException('Failed to load album.')`, which has the catch-all pattern `_`, so if the matched value doesn't match the map pattern, the switch throws.
Having a catch-all case at the end is common in switch expressions, because they *must* be exhaustive. An expression must have a value, even if it's just `_ => null` or `_ => throw SomeError("Nothing matched!")`.

The factory's pattern code is pretty much equivalent to:

```dart
  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final Album $switchResult;
    switchExpression:
    {
      // No need to check that value is `Map`, static type guarantees it.
      final userId = json['userId'];
      if (userId is int) {
        final id = json['id'];
        if (id is int) {
          final title = json['title'];
          if (title is String) {
            $switchResult = Album(userId: userId, id: id, title: title);
            // Successful match, skip later patterns.
            break switchExpression;
          }
        }
      }
      // Match-all pattern, unconditionally evaluate
      $switchResult = throw const FormatException('Failed to load album.');
    }
    return $switchResult;
  }
```